# R geom_bar not aligning with X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 tables of data to plot which are structurally identical, but the resulting plots are quite different using geom_bar() in ggplot (R 4.1.0, tidyverse). Below, in Plot 1 (generated from t1) the bar arrangement on the X axis overlaps adjacent values on the scale, whereas in Plot 2 (generated from t2) they align as I would expect. I cannot figure out why this would be - can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks

Table 1:

```
t1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2021, 2021, 2021), 
        Area = c("1a", "1b", "2", "1a", "1b", "2"), Value = c(131.333333333333, 
        75, 90, 178.2, 247.444444444444, 152.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), groups = structure(list(Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2021, 
    2021, 2021), Area = c("1a", "1b", "2", "1a", "1b", "2"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Table 2:

```
t2 <- structure(list(Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2021, 
    2021, 2021), Area = c("1a", "1b", "2", "1a", "1b", "2", "1a", 
    "1b", "2"), Value = c(331.764705882353, 306.666666666667, 229.538461538462, 
    274.235294117647, 268.846153846154, 209.642857142857, 374.058823529412, 
    333.833333333333, 189.545454545455)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(
        Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2021, 2021, 
        2021), Area = c("1a", "1b", "2", "1a", "1b", "2", "1a", "1b", 
        "2"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
            8L, 9L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Plot code (swap t1/t2):

```
p <- ggplot(t1,aes(x=Year,y=Value,fill=Area)) +
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.9),stat="identity")
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the online doc:

Dodging preserves the vertical position of an geom while adjusting the horizontal position. position_dodge() requires the grouping variable to be be specified in the global or geom_* layer. Unlike position_dodge(), position_dodge2() works without a grouping variable in a layer. position_dodge2() works with bars and rectangles, but is particulary useful for arranging box plots, which can have variable widths.

So,

```
ggplot(t1,aes(x=Year,y=Value,fill=Area)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge2(.9),stat="identity")
```

[image]

**Edit in response to OP's comment below**

`ggplot()` can only plot data that it knows about.  You only have data for 2018 and 2021 in `t1`, so that's all it can plot.  The overlap is caused by the interaction of this "missing" data, the fact that `Year` is a continuous variable, and the other aesthetics in the plot.

A simple solution is to put the missing data back.  To do this, I need to `ungroup` the sample data because you can't add rows to a `group`ed data frame.  But that's not a problem.  The grouping is irrelevant here.

```
t1 %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  add_row(Year=2019, Area="1a", Value=0) %>% 
  add_row(Year=2019, Area="1b", Value=0) %>% 
  add_row(Year=2019, Area="2", Value=0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=Value,fill=Area)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.9),stat="identity")
```

[image]

Alternatively, convert year to a factor:

```
t1 %>% mutate(Year=factor(Year, levels=2018:2021))%>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=Value,fill=Area)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.9),stat="identity")
```

[image]

It never hurts to look at your data from time to time.  *Thinking* about your data is even better.

Comment: Thanks but the plot is still not correct - the bars still overlap the wrong values on the X axis. There should be 3 bars per single X axis value as per Plot 2.

Comment: Thanks again - I'd hoped to avoid a workaround, it still doesn't explain why ggplot apparently interprets the data differently in the 2 plots despite them both having missing entries for the continuous X axis, it's the lack of consistency that seems strange. Also +1 for the patronising end notes, nice touch.